# Completeness axiom in $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt2 )$??

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt2 )$ is a field that not satisfy the completeness axiom but i'm not sure how to atack this problem.
I already showed that $\mathbb{Q} (\sqrt2 )$ is a field.

Comment: I believe $\sqrt3\notin\Bbb Q(\sqrt2)$.

Comment: thank you  it was really helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The completeness axiom says that every subset that's bounded above has a least upper bound.  A typical counterexample showing that the rational numbers do not satisfy it is
$$
    A = \left\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^2 \leq 2 \right\}
$$
This set is bounded above (for instance, by $2$), but it has no least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$.  Such a least upper bound, if it existed, would need to be the square root of $2$, and we know that's not in $\mathbb{Q}$.

This counterexample obviously won't work with your field $K = \mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{2}\right)$, since in fact $\sqrt{2}\in K$.  But maybe you could adapt it?